# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library imagic.so

Tags: php, linux, centos, imagick

me and my server guys are stuck with this error, which is really annoying.

the system is sending me email for every 10 minutes

```
Cron <root@94> /usr/local/psa/admin/bin/php -c '/usr/local/psa/admin/conf/php.ini' -dauto_prepend_file=sdk.php '/usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/plesk-mobile/scripts/push_worker.php'


PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/sw-engine/imagick.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/sw-engine/imagick.so: undefined symbol: OnUpdateBool in Unknown on line 0
```

the imagick is working fine,

1. re installed the imagic
2. i have checked the php.ini file and imagick.so is there
3. and the imagick.so file is there.
4. changed the file permissions

so what do you think it might be causing this emails ?

Comment: `undefined symbol: OnUpdateBool in Unknown on line 0` the problem is not that you are missing the library, is that the library cannot be loaded because of this. Perhaps you have a update query in one of the associated php scripts that fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(after 3 months -- I hope this helps somebody)
I had PHP errors all of a sudden regarding "imagic.so" on my hostmonster site.  My PHP was at
"PHP 5.2 (Single php.ini)". I changed it to
"PHP 5.4 (Single php.ini)" and the errors stopped.

Comment: you are right, the errors gone after i updated the php version too, but i forgot to mention the solution here, so i will accept yours as correct answer, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The error message `undefined symbol: OnUpdateBool in Unknown on line 0` indicates that when your system is trying to load the imagick.so library, it is trying and failing, to call the function 'OnUpdateBool'.

That is a function in PHP and has been there since [for about 14 years](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/Zend/zend_ini.c?a=true&h=#549)....

I think either your installation of PHP has been corrupted, or there is some other very weird behaviour that is happening e.g. someone sneakily installed HHVM while you weren't looking.

If your system was working before, you need to find what has changed and work from there.

Comment: i have installed the php again, there is no HHVM, the system is working fine now too, no problems with imagick but this error is coming up still