# Php Imagick error: undefined symbol FT_Done_MM_Var, how can i fix it?

Tags: php, linux, xampp, fedora, imagick

Complete output:

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imagick.so' (tried: /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/imagick.so (/lib64/libharfbuzz.so.0: undefined symbol: FT_Done_MM_Var), /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/imagick.so.so (/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20190902/imagick.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

My OS: Fedora 36
Installed packages: ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel ImageMagick-perl php php-common php-pear php-devel gcc php-imagick.

Imagics.so installed via pecl in xampp

Comment: It looks like your system is missing the [imagick](https://github.com/imagick/imagick) PHP extension package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library imagic.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717734/php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-imagic-so)

Comment: I have imagick extension and this answer does not help me. I am just update my php to latest and install imagick7, and it helps me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, to install imagick on xampp on fedora you need to type the following commands:

```
sudo dnf install ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel ImageMagick-libs ImageMagick-perl
sudo dnf install php-pecl-imagick php-pecl-imagick-devel 
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/pecl install imagick
```

It is important to install ImageMagick instead of ImageMagick7 and install php-pecl-imagick and not php-pecl-imagick-im6 or im7.